# how to call java bean method at every click on button

Tags: onclick, richfaces, javabeans

I have jsf component commandButton and I want that at every clock on this button to call bean method "initialize()", but with this code it was called only once at page loading

code is here 
http://pastebin.com/MjW1TJxF

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html):

> onclick - Javascript code executed when a pointer button is clicked over this element.

If you want something to happen on server side, use the `actionListener` attribute.

(And next time, you can put your code into the question)